# Divide a string into two in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter, and I want to ask is it possible to divide a string into two
for example I have 
`$a="hello+man"` and I want `$b=hello` and `$c=man,` I have searched a lot of functions but they actually delete characters from strings

help

Comment: That is not a 'code igniter' question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exist a function in php `explode` that help you to do what you want
try this:

```
$a="hello+man";
$stringarr = explode('+',$a);
$b = $stringarr[0]; //hello
$c = $stringarr[1]; //man
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an explode?

```
$words = explode("+", $a);
$b = $words[0];
$c = $words[1];
```

This allows you to use delimiters and store the results in an array

Answer (score 0):

Or, just one line:

```
list($b, $c) = explode('+', $a);
```